# What happens if you transfer a fully EV trained LVL 100 Pokémon from Gen 2 to Pokémon Home?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal, pokemon-home

Basically, on modern gen Pokémon games, you can only EV train and max up to 2 EV stat at most (255-255 or 252-252-4). But in Pokémon Crystal Gen 2, you could EV train and max all EV stats, meaning it's stronger than those that were EV trained in the newer generations.

I heard that EVs would reset to 0 after transfer, but would that mean the additional stat gained through trick box or by leveling a fully EV trained Pokémon from Gen 2 will have its stats reduced and balanced after the transfer, after it had its EVs reset to zero?

Comment: Not related, but making it 255-255 is completely waste of EV points since because stats are calculated by dividing effort by 4 and disregarding the remainder (that's why almost everyone's running 252-252-4).

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/302347/87579).

Comment: There are no EVs in gen 2; it's called stat experience instead and works completely differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Transporter#:%7E:text=Stat%20experience%20is%20completely%20erased,%2C%2011%2C%2014%20or%2015.):

> Stat experience is completely erased, so the transferred Pokémon has 0 EVs.

Basically, when you use the Poké Transporter to transport a Pokémon from Gen 2 into Pokémon Bank (and thence to Pokémon Home) the stat experience will be removed, meaning the Pokémon will have 0 EVs. The statistics themselves will then be calculated based on the 0 EVs (so all the statistics will go down from the fully trained version). The final statistics will be the same as for any freshly caught Pokémon of level 100 with 0 EVs and the same IVs. In modern games, statistics are updated immediately, rather than needing a level or the box trick from earlier gens - so you can apply EVs to the level 100 Pokémon and have it update to show the new EVs even without levelling it.